# predict() functionality usage in rms package

Tags: r

I have created a regression model using `ols()` from `rms` package

```
data_Trans <- ols(Check ~ rcs(data_XVar,6))
```

Since this is built using restricted cubic spline with 6 knots I get 5 coefficients with one intercept.

Now I could not understand how to apply this model over new sets of coefficient values. Any example to perform this would be really helpful.Further, I am not sure whether we have specify any knot positions or the model saves the previous knot positions saved while building the model.

Comment: Maybe reading `?predict.ols` might help.

Comment: Hello Pascal, Thank you for the input. I have been trying to understand the same for this specific task, however can't understand it as of now. I will keep trying.